# post variable in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to use the post variable value in my sql query to sort data in order chosen by a user. The table gets displayed correctly with appropriate fields but the values are not sorted.

I'm aware this is subject to sql injection, however, I'm doing this for training purposes on my local server.

```
<?php
$sort_in = $_POST['SortIn'];

$sql = 'select * from db.Runner order by "'.$_POST['SortIn'].'"';
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

    if($result)
    {
        echo "<table border = '1'>
        <tr>
        <th>RunnerID</th>
        <th>EventID</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['RunnerID'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row['EventID'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: If you're doing it for training purposes, you should ditch the obsolete/deprecated mysql_*() functions and learn with at least mysqli, or PDO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently producing and running a query like

```
select * from db.Runner order by "fieldname";
```

which should of course be either of

```
select * from db.Runner order by fieldname;
select * from db.Runner order by `fieldname`;  -- for MySql
select * from db.Runner order by [fieldname];  -- for MSSQL
```

(I suggest one of the last two, depending on your database, in case your field name happens to be "order", for example).

Remove the double quotes

```
$sql = 'select * from db.Runner order by '.$_POST['SortIn'];
```

and possibly replace them by the appropriate delimiter, e.g.

```
$sql = 'select * from db.Runner order by `'. $_POST['SortIn'] . '`';
```

You already mentioned SQL injection and mysql_ vs mysqli_ so I'll keep my mouth shut today ;) Although I don't really see a reason - even for a training project on `localhost` - not to do it right, to be honest.

[edit]After posting this answer, some useful comments were made to your OP by `MarcB` and to the other answer by `zan`. Despite this being training, please heed them, as they are good advice!

Comment: I'd like to add another variable $_POST['SortBy'] to sort in descending order if a user wishes to do that. How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: You could pass in `SortOrder` as `+1` or `-1` and add something like `($_POST['SortOrder'] == -1 ? "DESC" : "ASC")` to your query.

Answer (score 1):

You actually sorting on a string instead of a field, remove the quotes in the query:

```
$sql = 'select * from db.Runner order by '.$_POST['SortIn'];
```

P.S. I won't start a rant about the injection ;)

Comment: If I wanted to sort in asc or dsc order specified in another post variables, how would I do that without those two variables being concatenated?

Comment: @zan Before you cancatenate, verify the variable is valid by whitelisting.